# Python Pillow trying to change resolution of photo while same proportion

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create something with Pillow. The Problem is the following. I have a photo like with a resolution of  612 * 563.

[image]

I would like to change the height of this photo while the Proportion stays like in picture one.
If I try to change the resolution for instance to 612 * 500 the tire gets wider.

[image]

That's not how I want it. Is there a way in pillow how I can change the resolution (height) of the photo while keeping the original proportions?

I have now added the following code, which was given by Kris. Unfortunately it still does not seem to work.

[Code Sample Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au4UL.jpg)

Python does not say that theres a mistake but it does not save a file at all. The new picture should be saved under the name "ReifenTest1" or am I wrong?

Comment: Paste the code in your question instead of just linking an image containing it.

Comment: Your image save code is wrong. you should indent it outside the function, and use the image coming as a return value of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the thumbnail method from PIL to obtain a resized image that keeps the original aspect ratio.

```
from PIL import Image

target_width = 612
target_height = 500
maxsize = (target_width, target_height)
path_to_the_image = /path/to/the/image
image = Image.open(path_to_the_image)
image.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save("resized-image.*") # change the * for png/jpeg/etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to resize maintaining aspect ratio.
Then it will be ok.
See an example here.

```
def auto_resize(image_im: Image.Image, max_height):
    if image_im:
        width, height = image_im.size # get the current size
        if height > max_height:
            aspect = width / height # find the aspect ratio
            r_height = max_height # Set your needed height
            r_width = int(r_height * aspect) #Calcualte the width for lock on proportions
            image_im = image_im.resize((r_width, r_height)) # resize then!
    return image_im
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the Code Example given by Chris. Unfortunately it still does not seem to work. If someone could have a look at it this would be a real blessing for me! Thanks.